# How to revert back to python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, symlink, virtualenvwrapper

Whenever I ran `python --version` the result was 2.7 and 3.8 for `python3 --version`. I wanted to get 3.8 by running only `python --version` instead of `python3 --version` and after looking for the same on stackoverflow I did this

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
```

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

and while it did what I wanted but now a lot of things are going haywire. Therefore, I want my system to go back to the way it was before.

P.S. I wanted python to call python3 in the first place because whenever I would run `mkvirtualenv name` it would give me a warning that I am using python 2.7 and should switch to 3.8 but python 3.8 was already there on my computer and I thought maybe by doing the above mentioned I would get rid of the warning.

Comment: (If you need a python3 version quick, just use [Google Colab](http://colab.research.google.com/), so there is no need to bother with this stuff.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: This is giving output `rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/python': No such file or directory`.

Comment: @RoshinRaphel Thanks. Could you also help with virtualenvwrapper running with python2 instead of python3 as after creating the virtualenv I got `Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2`